# Getting count of stored procedure ran on SQL Server per database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked to log all SP execution for all databases on all servers. My plan is to create a SSIS Package which will run a query and it will add a resultset of all the servers to a table.

Query that I found available on many forums is as below. Which gives result of active database of the server. I use `EXEC sp_MSforeachdb` for running it on every database.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? ;
SELECT Db_name(database_id)               databaes_name,
   p.name                                 proc_name,
   p.type                                 proc_type,
   execution_count,
   CONVERT(date, getdate()) as ForDate
FROM   sys.procedures p
   JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats d
       ON p.object_id = d.object_id
WHERE  d.database_id = Db_id() order by execution_count desc'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Which gives result in below manner.

```
|databaes_name | proc_name | proc_type | execution_count |ForDate   |
.....................................................................
|MyDB          | procedure1|P          | 12354           |2016-12-02|
|MyDB          | procedure1|P          | 13254           |2016-12-02|

|databaes_name | proc_name | proc_type | execution_count |ForDate   |
.....................................................................
|MyDB2         | proc1     |P          | 1254            |2016-12-02|
```

What I want in my query is, it should count all the execution of all the SPs and it should give me result as shown in below table.

```
|databaes_name | proc_type  | execution_count|ForDate   |
.........................................................
|MyDB          | P          | 256088         |2016-12-02|
|MyDB2         | P          | 1254           |2016-12-02|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing query from question to get the summation of the execution count.

```
SELECT 
   Db_name(database_id)               databaes_name,
   p.type                             proc_type,
   SUM(execution_count)               executionCount,
   CONVERT(date, getdate()) as ForDate
FROM   sys.procedures p
   JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats d
       ON p.object_id = d.object_id
WHERE  d.database_id = Db_id() 
GROUP BY database_id, p.type
ORDER BY SUM(execution_count) DESC
```

Please note that above query is generated based on an assumption that `sys.procedures p INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats d ON p.object_id = d.object_id` works for you as mentioned in question.

As mentioned in the edit, if you want to have your output generated by sp_MSforeachdb, you can use below approach to first gather the data in the temp table or table variable (I prefer table variable over temp table).

```
DECLARE @vRestultSet TABLE(DB_Name VARCHAR(100), ProcType VARCHAR(100), Execution_Count INT, ExecutionDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @vResultSet
SELECT * FROM sp_MSforeachdb @command;
SELECT 
    DB_Name
    , ProcType
    , SUM(Execution_Count)
    , ExecutionDate
FROM @vResultSet
GROUP BY DB_Name, ProcType, ExecutionDate;
```

Make sure to define the column in table variables are per your output. Also please feel free to change the logic of `GROUP BY` statement if required.

If you want to group your result by day then you might need to covert the `Execution_Date` into Day part using `CONVERT` or any other method.

Comment: I have just added more clarification on how I am using this query. Just wanted to add one more thing your answer is sufficient for what I described earlier.